# How to perform forEach loop in Java

Tags: java

I am a Javascript developer and I starting to check out Java.

One question that I have is how I can perform forEach on a collection. I can't seem to find any such method in Java collections...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work   These links helps you

Comment: @devnull - Maybe because there exisits no `method` for this but only syntatic iteration in form of a for. A `method` would be something like: collection.ForEach(//do something in here...);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java 5, you can use the *enhanced `for` loop* for this. Assume you have (say) a `List<Thingy>` in the variable `thingies`. The enhanced `for` loop looks like this:

```
for (Thingy t : thingies) {
    // ...
}
```

As of Java 8, there's an actual [`forEach` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) on iterables that accepts a [lambda function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
thingies.forEach((Thingy t) -> { /* ...your code here... */ });
```

If you have an existing method you want to use, you can use a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) instead of an inline lambda:

```
thingies.forEach(this::someMethod);      // Instance method on `this`
thingies.forEach(SomeClass::someMethod); // Static method on `SomeClass`
thingies.forEach(foo::someMethod);       // Instance method on `foo` instance
```

Comment: And if `your code here` amounts to `someMethod(t)`, you get to write just `thingies.forEach(this::someMethod)`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Oh very cool! I've added examples and a link to the JLS for that, thanks. (Haven't got into this Java 8 stuff much yet.)

Comment: The answer grows and grows in perfectness. :D

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish can only be done in a form similar to JavaScript, in Java 8 or newer.
Java 8 added the forEach (defender) method on Iterable (for which Collection inherits)

Comment: Strange answer, you are implying he cannot do a for each loop similar to JavaScript in Java < 8?

Comment: The user obviously does not want a for loop but a forEach method on a collection

Comment: The *enhanced* `for` loop (`for (Thingy t : collectionOfT)`) was added to [**Java 5**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.14.2) (e.g., many years ago), not Java 8.

Comment: Again, I am not talking about for(Integer obj : myCollection) {}, I am talking about myCollection.forEach();

Comment: @geoand: JavaScript has the `for-in` statement, which is very like the enhanced `for` statement. I think you're being a bit over-literal with the OP referencing `forEach`. But yes, collections only got the lambda version recently.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see where you are coming from, but my understanding of the question was that the asker had code like var a = ["a", "b", "c"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});

and wanted to translate it to a Java collection without the for loop

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Since OP is explicitly asking for a *`forEach` method of the `Collection` interface*, I think this answer fits best. The enhanced for loop also deserves a mention, but this answer fits the question squarely.

Comment: He is asking how to *perform forEach on a collection*, i.e. he is asking how to iterate a collection. Not necessarily a literal method by the name of `forEach`. That would be my interpretation.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers How about "I can't find any such method in Java collections"?